# UI-Sortable - Ajax and cancel does not work

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

Im using AngularJs together with Ui-sortable (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable). My use case is basically for dragging & dropping in the same list.

The usual drag and drop an item of the list (I mean, update the position of an item) works. My issue comes when Im trying to add an Ajax call to check if the movement is allowed. If the movement is not allowed, it should be canceled. The canceling is the part that I cannot make run well.

Maybe with some code this is easier to understand:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    'ui-floating': false,
    update : function(e, ui) {
        // Check distance of movement
        var diffIndex   = _computeDiff(ui.item.sortable);

        var moveObject = {"operation": "move", "value": diffIndex};

        // Http call to do move
        HttpApi.post('check', moveObject).then(function(){
            // TESTING: Im trying to Cancel all the movements
            // When this code is executed, sortable has already trigger stop.
            // Canceling does not work anymore.
            ui.item.sortable.cancel();  
        });
    }
};
```

Any suggestions about how to handle it?

Comment: Same problem here. Could you solve it?